# Matplotlib: animate large data set

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, optimization, graph

I have CSV file with 20 joints of human body in XYZ and i need to animate then in XY axis and ZY axis. I used `pandas` to collect data from CSV file and     `scatter set_offsets`

where i placed collected data like

```
def _update_plot_XY(self, i, fig, scat):
    scat.set_offsets((
        (self.data.HeadX[i], self.data.HeadY[i]),
        (self.data.ShoulderCenterX[i], self.data.ShoulderCenterY[i]),
        (self.data.SpineX[i], self.data.SpineY[i]),
        (self.data.HipCenterX[i], self.data.HipCenterY[i]),
        (self.data.ShoulderLeftX[i], self.data.ShoulderLeftY[i]),
        (self.data.ElbowLeftX[i], self.data.ElbowRightY[i]),
        (self.data.WristRightX[i], self.data.WristRightY[i]), (self.data.HandRightX[i], self.data.HandRightY[i]),
        (self.data.HandLeftX[i], self.data.HandLeftY[i]),
        (self.data.ShoulderRightX[i], self.data.ShoulderRightY[i]),
        (self.data.ElbowRightX[i], self.data.ElbowRightY[i]),
        (self.data.WristLeftX[i], self.data.WristLeftY[i]), (self.data.HipLeftX[i], self.data.HipLeftY[i]),
        (self.data.KneeLeftX[i], self.data.KneeLeftY[i]),
        (self.data.AnkleLeftX[i], self.data.AnkleLeftY[i]),
        (self.data.FootLeftX[i], self.data.FootLeftY[i]), (self.data.HipRightX[i], self.data.HipRightY[i]),
        (self.data.KneeRightX[i], self.data.KneeRightY[i]),
        (self.data.AnkleRightX[i], self.data.AnkleRightY[i]), (self.data.FootRightX[i], self.data.FootRightY[i])))
    return scat
```

I know that FPS is 33

```
self.anim_XY = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.human._update_plot_XY, fargs=(self.fig, scat2),
                                             frames=self.human.frames, interval=33, repeat=False)
```

I try to plot every graph in new figure, but it's looks terrible.
Is there  any other option to increase FPS?

Comment: Choosing a lower number for `interval` will increase the frames per second. But there is a limit on how fast matplotlib can draw the figure. Often `blit=True` would help.